# Cursor Adapter and Multiple Columns Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

I have a listfragment that I'm populating with a simplecursoradapter. However, only the first column is getting binded to the layout. Here is the code.

```
public class ContactList extends ListFragment

{
private ActivityDbAdapter mDbHelper;
private Long mRowId=Long.valueOf(1);
Activity mContext;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    mContext=getActivity();
    mDbHelper=new ActivityDbAdapter(mContext);
    mDbHelper.open();
    Cursor activity = mDbHelper.fetchContacts(mRowId);
    if (activity.moveToFirst())
    {


    String[] from = new String[]{ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT1 ,
            ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT2,ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT3,
            ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT4, ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT5};



    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.contacts};

    SimpleCursorAdapter contacts = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext, R.layout.activity_contact_row, activity, from, to);

    setListAdapter(contacts);
    }

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contact_list, container, false);

}

}
```

... So here only Contact1 is showing up in the layout. Or whichever column I have first.  From what I understood reading was that I didn't have to utilize a for loop to correctly bind all of the columns, but it seems that you do? Unless I'm missing something here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the names of the columns you're fetching from the db? The "from" should be the columnnames of the table in your db. Here's a good example: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Comment: They're the correct columns. I'm getting the right values. But only from the first position of the array. I.e., I get "first person" the way the code looks right now, but then I removed first person and I got "second person" in the layout. So the values are correct, I'm just only getting one value.

Comment: But this line: mDbHelper.fetchContacts(mRowId) what does it do? And how many rows does it return if you call activity.getCount() on it?
Also the 'from' and 'to' array should probably have the same amount of items.

Comment: It's only one row. I'm using this for a research project so I purposely made one row for each person so it will be easier for me to compile and analyze in a csv file on a remote server. Maybe I'm just not understanding the Cursor Adapter correctly. From what I understood it would iterate over the from and push it to the to, but I'm guessing a need to make an extra "to" for each contact.

Comment: Nope that's not how it works. Look at the link I posted at first. From the link: "// THE DESIRED COLUMNS TO BE BOUND
String[] columns = new String[] { People.NAME, People.NUMBER };
// THE XML DEFINED VIEWS WHICH THE DATA WILL BE BOUND TO
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_entry, R.id.number_entry };"
The 'from' array holds the different columns for each row of your cursor. The 'to' is the id's of the views the columns should be bound to.

Comment: Got it. But if I have multiple rows it will iterate over each of those, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one item (`R.id.contacts`) inside your array `to`; therefore only one view is used/displayed for the data.  You need to add the Ids for the other views, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Method into your `ListFragment` instead of old one.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    mContext=getActivity();
    mDbHelper=new ActivityDbAdapter(mContext);

    mDbHelper.open();
    Cursor activity = mDbHelper.fetchContacts(mRowId);
    mDbHelper.close();

    String[] from = new String[]{ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT1 ,
            ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT2,ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT3,
            ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT4, ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_CONTACT5};


    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.contacts};

    SimpleCursorAdapter contacts = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext, R.layout.activity_contact_row, activity, from, to);

    setListAdapter(contacts);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contact_list, container, false);

}
```

Comment: Yes I do. I think its a problem with my xml file. Thanks for the help though.